# Show that the solution to an IVP blows up in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the solution to the IVP $$x'(t) = t + e^{-t}e^x, \hspace{0.5mm} x(0) = 0 $$ blows up in finite time. That is, I want to find a $T > 0$ such that $x(t)$ is defined on $[0,T)$ and $x(t) \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow T^{-}$.

I haven't even managed to find a solution to the IVP. I thought that if I could find the solution, then I could "simply" find a $T$ such that that solution blows up when $t \rightarrow T$.

The closest I've come to finding a solution is the following: I found that if $x(t) = \frac{t^2}{2} - e^xe^{-t} + h(x)$, then $x'(t) = t + e^{-t}e^x$. And then setting $x(0) = 0$ gives $h(x) = e^x$. So $x(t) = \frac{t^2}{2} - e^{-t}e^x + e^x$ should (?) solve the IVP. If this was indeed the way to go, then how would I go from here to find a $T$ such that $x(t) \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: in the first displayed equation, with $e^x$ do you mean $e^{x(t)}$ ?

Comment: I think it is $$x \left( t \right) =1/2\,{t}^{2}-\ln  \left( 1/2\,{\frac {i\sqrt {\pi}
\sqrt {2}{\rm erf} \left(i/2\sqrt {2}t-i/2\sqrt {2}\right)-2\,{\it 
\_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{1/2}}}{{{\rm e}^{1/2}}}} \right) $$

Comment: Good question. The problem as is it stated in my literature says $e^x$, not $e^{x(t)}$. It didn't occur to me that there would be a difference... @Hayk

Comment: @RickS $x(0) = 0$ indicates $x$ must be a function of some variable. The only variable that seems to occur in the question is $t$.

Comment: What is your motivation for thinking that the solution blows up in finite time?

Comment: Your approach with $h(x)$ doesn't quite work. You say $$x(t) = \frac{t^2}{2} - e^{t} e^{x(t)} + e^{x(t)}$$ and that doesn't really make sense. Why would $h$ depend on $x$ and not on $t$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Whats $C1$ in your solution? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%27(t)+%3D+t+%2B+e%5Et+e%5E(x(t))+and+x(0)+%3D+0) has a slightly similar result.

Comment: $$C_1$$ is a real constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that nasty $e^x$ nonlinear term, it suggests setting $x = a\ln u$, then adjusting $a$ to make a linear equation. This works for $a = -1$, so we set $x = -\ln u$ and get
$$
u'(t) + t u(t) = - e^{-t}\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\; u(0)  = 1.
$$
This first-order equation can be solved with the integrating factor $e^{t^2/2}$, giving
$$
\int_0^t\frac{d}{dt'}\left[e^{t'^2/2}u(t')\right]dt' = e^{t^2/2}u(t) - u(0) = -\int_0^te^{t'^2/2-t'}dt'.
$$
So 
$$
u(t) = e^{-t^2/2}\left[1 - \int_0^te^{t'^2/2-t'}dt'\right].
$$
Since $x = -\ln u$, it blows up when $u(T) = 0$, which happens when
$$
\int_0^Te^{t'^2/2-t'}dt' = 1.
$$
Since $e^{t'^2-t'}$ is an unbounded function, this must happen at some finite $T$ (and indeed, it happens near $T = 1.44$).

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=e^{x-t}$. Then $u'=u(t-1+u)$ with $u(0)=1$ is a Bernoulli equation. With the usual substitution $u=v^{-1}$ this transforms into the linear ODE
$$
-v'=(t-1)v+1, ~~ v(0)=1\implies v(t)=e^{-\frac12(t-1)^2}\left[\sqrt{e}-\int_{-1}^{t-1}e^{+\frac12s^2}ds\right]
$$
As the integral term grows to infinity, $v$ will have a root that is then a pole for $u$ and a blow-up point for the solution of the IVP. The root is close to $T\approx 1.4392$